# Yeoman and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have been trying to install Yeoman and get it configured on Ubuntu 12.04. (running in Vmware)

Had it working at one stage then I come back from lunch and try it and its not reading where my generators are.

What I have done:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs

npm config set prefix ~/npm        
#added to ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$HOME/npm/bin:$PATH

yo wasnt being read at one stage so I did this 
$ sudo npm rm -g yo  
npm cache clean  
$ sudo npm install -g yo
```

I was also getting access errors so I did this

```
chmod 775 .npm   
chmod 775 .npm/touch
```

Everything is there in `~/npm/lib/node_modules` but it just doesnt seem to be finding them.

Wrecking my head at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to download a new generator I ran into an issue regarding my NODE_PATH:
 - NODE_PATH
   =/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
 - NPM root  = /home/carlos/npm/lib/node_modules/lib/node_modules
 - [Fix] Append the NPM root value to your NODE_PATH variable
 - Add this line to your .bashrc

```
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/carlos/npm/lib/node_modules/lib/node_modules
```

Or run this command

```
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/carlos/npm/lib/node_modules/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashr
```

I added the line to my ~/.bashrc and it seems to have sorted the issue. My generators are now showing up.

I ended up writing a [post about my issues with yemoan and nodejs](http://outofabrownpaperbag.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/nodejs-npm-and-yeoman-on-ubuntu-12-04-part-2-kind-of/)
The problems I was having were permission problems which were in relation to nodejs, npm, and where things were being installed.